# Passing variable to href django template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have some problem and maybe I can give an example of two views below what I want to achieve.

```
class SomeViewOne(TemplateView):
    model = None
    template_name = 'app/template1.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # The downloads view contains a list of countries eg France, Poland, Germany
        # This returns to context and lists these countries in template1
  
class ItemDetail(TemplateView):
    model = None
    template_name = 'app/template2.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        countries_name = kwargs.get('str')
        The view should get the passed "x" with the name of the country where I described it 
        below.
```

Then on the page I have a list of these countries.
After clicking on the selected country, a new tab should open and show a list of cities in the selected country.

So I am using in loop template1.html as below

```
{% for x in list_countries %}
    <li>
      <a href="{% url 'some-name-url' '{{x}}' %}" class="target='_blank'">{{ x }}</a><br>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**I can't pass "x" this way. Why?**

The url for the next view looks like this

```
path('some/countries/<str:x>/',views.ItemDetail.as_view(), name='some-name-url'),
```

And I can't get that 'x' given in the template in the href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Manoj's solution doesn't work, try removing the single quotes AND {{ }}. In my program, my integer doesnt need to be wrapped with {{ }}, so maybe neither does your string.
I have this in my code:

```
{% for item in items %}

        <div class="item-title">
          {{ item }}<br>
        </div>
        <a href="{% url 'core:edit_item' item.id %}">Edit {{ item }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

It works just fine. Try:

```
<a href="{% url 'some-name-url' x %}" class="target='_blank'">{{ x }}</a>
```

Comment: @Hide856 Also see my [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74489351/17562044) answer it will also work for `target=_blank` and also have some corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need pass that variable with single quotes.

```
<a href="{% url 'some-name-url' {{ x }} %}" #Just removed single quotes from variable x.
```

And see if it shows on template

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes such as:

1. It should be only `x` in url tag neither `{{x}}` nor `'{{x}}'`
2. you have passed the value as `x` in url params (`some/countries/<str:x>/`) and accessing it using `kwargs.get('str')` which is not correct it should be `kwargs.get('x')`.
3. Also you are not including variable `countries_name` in context and not even returning context.

> **Note:** Assuming that you are already getting some companies in `template1.html` template that's why you are running loop.

Try below code:

views.py

```py
class ItemDetail(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'template2.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['countries_name'] = self.kwargs.get('x')
        return context
```

Template1.html file

```html
{% for x in list_countries %}
    <li>
      <a onclick="window.open('{% url 'some-name-url' x %}', '_blank')" style='cursor:pointer;'>{{ x }}</a><br>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Then you can this `countries_name` value passed from `template1.html` in template2.html.

template2.html

```html
<p>The clicked country is {{countries_name}}</p>
```